# angular 5 calendar with month weeks and days view

Tags: calendar, angular5, responsive, schedule, angular-calendar

In work I am tasked to make a responsive schedule that tells the user his/her appointments today/week/month.

I found 
[Angular-calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar/tree/v0.24.1)
but I didn't get how to works because it the documentation was updated to angular 6 and I use 5

so is there any alternatives and if there's no alternatives how to use this calendar?

Answer (score 0):

> you can use "**angular-calendar**" library to display Calendar in angular

1. you can see the demo from this link [Angular Calendar Demo](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink)